# How to configure JaCoCo (to exclude some source files) for Android project with isTestCoverageEnabled=true

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, android-jacoco

The code coverage works perfectly fine for me when just set `isTestCoverageEnabled = true` in my BuildType Android Gradle configuration. It creates 2 tasks
`createReleaseUnitTestCoverageReport` for release build type and `createDebugUnitTestCoverageReport` for debug one.

The issue that all source files appear in the report and I would like to exclude some of them - e.g. Dagger generated classes etc.

According to the Android docs the only configuration to change is

```kotlin
testCoverage {
    jacocoVersion = "YOUR JACOCO VERSION"
}
```

and nothing else.

Since there is no `jacocoTestReport` task all solutions from StackOverflow don't work.

Is there any decent way to configure JaCoCo for Android except creating a custom `jacocoTestReport` task?